# Ruby - incorrect line break within statement still gives result?

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntax-error, line-breaks, multiline

The distilled script is the following:

```
z1 = (12 -
          2) / (5)
z2 = (12
        -  2) / (5)
puts(z1.to_s + " " + z2.to_s)
```

Which gives:

```
$ ruby rubytest.rb 
2 -1
```

Now, I'm aware that the `z1` case is the right way to do it, because a hanging operator on the end of the line is interpreted as an automatic continuation of the line.

However, I would expect the interpreter to fail-fast on the `z2` case, and tell me that the statement is incomplete, or that its second line is nonsensical. But it handles it "just fine" and gives the "-1" answer. Is it trying to appear confident by not admitting it's confused and hoping the bullshit answer will go unnoticed?

Could someone explain what is actually happening with the evaluation of `z2`, why is it "-1", why is there no syntax error, and is there an example where this behaviour is useful (or should we file a request to remove it)?

Comment: Interesting.  Change the 5 to 5.0.  Then you get -0.4 which implies it's completely ignoring the 12.  Doesn't explain what it thinks it's doing, but clarifies a little bit.

Comment: Hardly surprising, the same result is returned  if`(5)` is changed to `5`. I tried changing `5` to different values. If changed to `1`, `-2` is returned. Values great than `1` all seem to return `-1`.

Comment: Wow..Really looking forward to see the answer. Seems like it only calculate -2/5 from the second line. But if you use something which is not defined instead of 12 it will give NameError. I've also tried: 
`(2 + <new line here> -2/5)` and it will make 2 - 1 = 1. Crazy

Comment: Has someone checked to see if the same result is returned for different versions of Ruby? I'm using 2.1.0. For checking, I think it's sufficient to have just `(` on the first line and `-2)/5` on the second line.

Comment: I'm using `ruby 1.9.3p545 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32]`. Also, the `12` can be replaced with `nil`, or `"abcd"`, giving the same result. But not with gobbledygook, so it is evaluating it before discarding it.

Comment: In z2 wouldn't it read like this: `(12;` `(- 2 / 5)` resulting in -1 since ruby spits back the last thing evaluated?

Comment: @Anthony, except for the fact that it's `-2)/5`, not `(-2/5)`.

Comment: Right, I guess I'm simply stating that `(12; -2) / 5` also results in -1 and I believe that and OP's z2 are equivalent. Just found [this interesting bit of info](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.ruby/bug-multiline-ruby-expressions-with-parens/767491) regarding the issue.

Comment: In the interpreter `("abcd"; 3)` returns `3`. It's all starting to make sense. However, the question of how is this useful is still outstanding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a feature, but you might think it's a bug at first. It's for the same reason you are able to do this (which is handy many cases):

```
(call_function_1; call_function_2) if some_condition
```

A line feed is interpreted the same as `;`. You will notice this evaluates fine for example, and only the last expression is returned, but all expression ARE evaluated none the less:

```
(1
 2
 3
 4
 5)
=> 5
```

It's the same as

```
(1; 2; 3; 4; 5)
=> 5
```

To see that all expressions are evaluated you can try this for example:

```
(puts "A"
 puts "B"
 puts "C"
 123)
A
B
C
=> 123
```

So your example becomes:

```
(12; -2) / 5
```

Which is the same as:

```
-2 / 5
```

Which is `-1`.

To make Ruby interpret `12` as an unfinished statement and not a separate statement you can tell Ruby this by adding a line continuation hint `\`:

```
(12 \
 - 2) / 5
=> 2
```

Comment: I suppose some sort of `lint` for Ruby would have picked this up? (My initial reaction was that it's a bit of a reckless design, but upon further reflection, it fits with the general feel of Ruby, where the syntax is fluid and one has to be more wary of line breaks than usual. This handling of parentheses that span line breaks is one major syntactic pitfall for Python programmers writing Ruby and expecting superficial differences in syntax, but a similar underlying idea.)